# How do I prove $\operatorname{Hom}_R(A, B)$ torsion-free and divisible under the given conditions, where $A$ and $B$ are abelian groups.

Tags: homological-algebra

Let $A,B$ be abelian groups. I want to show that

> **(a)** the group $\operatorname{Hom}_R(A,B)$ is torsion-free when $A$ is divisible,

and

> **(b)** the group $\operatorname{Hom}_R(A,B)$ is divisible when $A$ is torsion-free and divisible.

Comment: Please always make the *body* of your questions self-contained: the question has to be complete even if one cannot see the title.

Comment: What is $R${}{}?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez This wasn't mentioned, can't it be an arbitrary ring?

Comment: If $R$ is to be anything but the integers, you need that $A$ and $B$ be $R$-modules, not just abelian groups for the question to make sense.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez You're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that $R$ should be $\mathbb{Z}$?

**(a)** If $\text{Hom}_\mathbb{Z}(A,B)$ is not torsion-free, then for some nonzero homomorphism $\varphi:A\to B$ there is a positive integer $n$ so that $n\varphi=0$. But for any $a\in A$, there is some $a'\in A$ with $a=na'$. So $\varphi(a)=n\varphi(a')=0$. Therefore $\varphi=0$, giving a contradiction.

**(b)** If also $A$ is torsion-free, then for any positive integer $n$ and any $a\in A$ there is a unique $a'\in A$ with $a=na'$ and $\theta:a\mapsto a'$ is a homomorphism $A\to A$. So for any homomorphism $\varphi:A\to B$, $\varphi=n\varphi\theta$, and so $\text{Hom}_\mathbb{Z}(A,B)$ is divisible.